# Strange Javascript Number Behavior - Cannot tell difference between 1 and 10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider, and each slide has content-editable set to true.  Meaning, each slide is basically a form.  Upon creating a slide, I embed a data-id attribute into each of the slide's fields, so that I can grab the field values from any particular slide.

The problem is, When I grab the field values with a data-id attribute set to `1` it also grabs the field values from the slide with a data-id attribute set to `10`.

Why is this happening?

Here is the code I use to grab any particular slide's values on an event trigger:

```
    var dealID = $(e.currentTarget).data("id");
    console.log("Deal ID: " + dealID);
    var dealTitleText = $('#deal-main-title[data-id*="' + dealID + '"]').text();
    var dealProvider = $('#deal-main-provider[data-id*="' + dealID + '"]').text();
    var dealDescription = $('#deal-main-description[data-id*="' + dealID + '"]').text();
    var dealPhoneNumber = $('#deal-main-phonenumber[data-id*="' + dealID + '"]').text();
    var dealConditions = $('#deal-main-conditions[data-id*="' + dealID + '"]').text();
```

Comment: Please abstract out that code so you're not repeating the same thing over and over. All you need to do is pass in the `title/provider` and the `dealID`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[data-id*="1"]` looks for all elements where `data-id` *contains* `1`. If you want equality, use just the equals sign:

```
$('#deal-main-title[data-id="' + dealID + '"]')
```

Comment: Nailed it!  In record time too...  Thanks Blender.